# md5 a string multiple times get different result on different platform

Tags: python, openssl, md5

t.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/md5.h>

static char* unsigned_to_signed_char(const unsigned char* in , int len) {
  char* res = (char*)malloc(len * 2 + 1);
  int i = 0;
  memset(res , 0 , len * 2 + 1);
  while(i < len) {
    sprintf(res + i * 2 , "%02x" , in[i]);
    i ++;
  };

  return res;
}

static unsigned char * md5(const unsigned char * in) {
  MD5_CTX ctx;
  unsigned char * result1 = (unsigned char *)malloc(MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH);
  MD5_Init(&ctx);
  printf("len: %lu \n", strlen(in));
  MD5_Update(&ctx, in, strlen(in));
  MD5_Final(result1, &ctx);
  return result1;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  const char * i = "abcdef";
  unsigned char * data = (unsigned char *)malloc(strlen(i) + 1);
  strncpy(data, i, strlen(i));  

  unsigned char * result1 = md5(data);
  free(data);
  printf("%s\n", unsigned_to_signed_char(result1, MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH));

  unsigned char * result2 = md5(result1);
  free(result1);
  printf("%s\n", unsigned_to_signed_char(result2, MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH));

  unsigned char * result3 = md5(result2);
  free(result2);
  printf("%s\n", unsigned_to_signed_char(result3, MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH));

  return 0;
}
```

makeflle

```
all:
cc t.c -Wall -L/usr/local/lib -lcrypto
```

and t.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import hashlib
import binascii

src = 'abcdef'

a = hashlib.md5(src).digest()
b = hashlib.md5(a).digest()
c = hashlib.md5(b).hexdigest().upper()

print binascii.b2a_hex(a)
print binascii.b2a_hex(b)
print c
```

The results of python script on Debian6 x86 and MacOS 10.6 are the same:

```
e80b5017098950fc58aad83c8c14978e
b91282813df47352f7fe2c0c1fe9e5bd
85E4FBD1BD400329009162A8023E1E4B
```

the c version on MacOS is:

```
len: 6 
e80b5017098950fc58aad83c8c14978e
len: 48 
eac9eaa9a4e5673c5d3773d7a3108c18
len: 64 
73f83fa79e53e9415446c66802a0383f
```

**Why it is different from Debian6 ?**

Debian environment:

```
gcc (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5
Python 2.6.6
Linux shuge-lab 2.6.26-2-686 #1 SMP Thu Nov 25 01:53:57 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux
```

OpenSSL was installed from testing repository.

MacOS environment:

```
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
Python 2.7.1
Darwin Lees-Box.local 10.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.7.0: Sat Jan 29 15:17:16 PST 2011; root:xnu-1504.9.37~1/RELEASE_I386 i386
```

OpenSSL was installed from MacPort.

```
openssl @1.0.0d (devel, security)
    OpenSSL SSL/TLS cryptography library
```

Comment: Can you print result of `strlen(in)` between `MD5_Init()` and `MD5_Update()`?

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged C or C++?  That's what the code is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are allocating bytes exactly for MD5 result, without ending `\0`. Then you are calculating MD5 of block of memory that starts with result from previous MD5 calculating but with some random bytes after it. You should allocate one byte more for result and set it to `\0`.

My proposal:

```
...
unsigned char * result1 = (unsigned char *)malloc(MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH + 1);
result1[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH] = 0;
...
```

Comment: I don't think the MD5 result is the problem; it's an array of `unsigned char`, of fixed length.  Binary data, which he converts to `char const*` using `sprintf`, which does append a `'\0'`.  (But the whole thing is easier and clearer using `std::vector` for the binary data, and `std::string` for the strings.)

Comment: James, the length is fixed, but not for `strlen()`. My proposal was to add NULL terminator, but author could as well add 2nd argument for `md5()` function with length of memory block for which this function will do calculations.

Answer (score 1):

The answers so far don't seem to me to have stated the issue clearly enough. Specifically the problem is the line:

```
  MD5_Update(&ctx, in, strlen(in));
```

The data block you pass in is not `'\0'` terminated, so the call to update may try to process further bytes beyond the end of the MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH buffer. In short, stop using `strlen()` to work out the length of an arbitrary buffer of bytes: you know how long the buffers are supposed to be so pass the length around.

Answer (score 0):

You don't `'\0'` terminate the string you're passing to `md5` (which I
suppose takes a `'\0'` terminated string, since you don't pass it the
length).  The code

```
memset( data, 0, sizeof( strlen( i ) ) );
memcpy( data, i, strlen( i ) );
```

is completely broken: `sizeof( strlen( i ) )` is the same as
`sizeof( size_t )`, 4 or 8 on typical machines.  But you don't want the
`memset` anyway.  Try replacing these with:

```
strcpy( data, i );
```

Or better yet:

```
std::string i( "abcdef" );
```

, then pass `i.c_str()` to `md5` (and declare `md5` to take a `char
const*`.  (I'd use an `std::vector<unsigned char>` in `md5()` as well,
and have it return it.  And `unsigned_to_signed_char` would take the
`std::vector<unsigned char>` and return `std::string`.)